# X-XSRF-TOKEN header with axios

Tags: axios, csrf, x-xsrf-token

Do I have to set anything to send `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header if I set a `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie server side?

https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/defaults.js#L74
https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/dist/axios.js#L1072

It reads like I don't, but I'm not seeing one go out.

I'll add that I have set `withCredentials` to true, so I do meet the first check in the OR:

```
var xsrfValue = (config.withCredentials || isURLSameOrigin(config.url)) && config.xsrfCookieName ?
            cookies.read(config.xsrfCookieName) :
            undefined;

          if (xsrfValue) {
            requestHeaders[config.xsrfHeaderName] = xsrfValue;
}
```

so if `config.xsrfCookieName` is a default.....

Update:

So, my `OPTIONS` preflight `CORS` is working, as is the `POST` now, but no `X-XSRF-TOKEN` being sent.

```
  methods: {
    onSubmit(e) {
      this.axios
        .post(
          e.target.action,
          { data: this.form },
          {
            withCredentials: true,
            xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN",
            xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
          }
        )
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.errors.push(err)
        })
    }
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Any ideas? https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1838

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and was about the "secure" flag on the cookie as can be seen on the cookies tab of the request, but is not showing on the cookies under "application" tab:

[image: XSRF-TOKEN secure]

In my case, I had to ask the backend to set it down.
This happens because, as secure, you cannot access to it via javascript.

```
document.cookie // is empty
```

Comment: "Secure" cookies *can* be read by javascript, it's Http-only ones that cannot. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#Secure "Cookies with this attribute can still be read/modified with access to the client's hard disk, or from JavaScript if the HttpOnly cookie attribute is not set."